# Scanf is requesting two strings at once

Tags: c, string, scanf, printf

In this segment of code the scanf is requesting twice and I am not sure what could be causing it to do so.

```
int t;
for(t = 0;t<5;t++)
{
    //scanf requests twice for some reason
    scanf("%s ",input);
    fprintf(fp,"%s ", input);
    printf("%d Word(s)\n", (t+2));
}
```

and the output is 
(words in quotes are entered in by the user)

```
"hello"
"world"
1 Word(s)
"how"
2 Word(s)
"are"
3 Word(s)
"you"
4 Word(s)
"lostword"
5 Word(s)
```

And

```
"hello world how are you "
```

would be given back to me and saved into the file.

Comment: Is that your *actual* code or an approximation ?

Comment: It is a excerpt of my code and input is a char array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the whitespace in scanf.

Change:

```
scanf("%s ",input);
```

to:

```
scanf("%s",input);
```

Due to the space, scanf keeps skipping whitespace characters until it reads something that's not a whitespace (after reading one string for `%s`).